# Implementing Multiple Login/Signup Systems in Django for Different User Types

Tags: python, django

I'm working on a Django project (Food delivery app) where I need to implement multiple login/signup systems for three types of users (in single project): customers, sellers, and drivers. Each user type has its own set of models, such as Customer, Seller, Driver, along with related
meta models like Seller Group / permissions / roles etc. Additionally, there are separate permission systems for each type.

My goal is to have different login/signup methods for each user type. For example:

- Customers log in/sign up using mobile OTP.
- Sellers log in/sign up using a business email and password.

I've organized my project into separate apps for each user type (customers, sellers, drivers), and I have custom user models.py defined in each app (AbstractUser, UserManager, PermissionMixins etc). But as per my knowledge, while using custom auth, I have to define `AUTH_USER_MODEL` in settings.py. where I can mention only one model.

How can I implement these different login/signup methods and ensure that the authentication and authorization processes are tailored to each user type? Are there Django packages or best practices for handling such scenarios?

Any guidance, code examples, or recommended resources would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Django follows another method, which is to put all users in one model and differentiate them by flags, this is how it separates is_superuser from is_staff and regular users.

I suggest you merge your users and separate them by a `user_role` field directing them to different homepages.

Another solution is to extend the User Model (as stated [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model)) so you put the common attributes in one model and create a model per role so you authenticate the users against base table.

Finally, you can create your [custom backend](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/topics/auth/customizing/#specifying-authentication-backends) and handle picking up the right table to authenticate your user.

For me, I'll go to the first solution of merging them all in one model and route to different homepage based on role.

Comment: Thanks. I have a little confusion, In a single table, if I register as a seller and then I want to register as a customer as well, there cud be an issue if I use UNIQUE on email? Even I login customer with OTP, still while registration, I need to fill in form.

Comment: You can say that email is already taken, I think this is a common practice except if you can allow each customer to be a seller, like Amazaon which allows each user to have their own store.